# Can I fit a 16 amp fuse into a UK domestic 13 amp plug?

Tags: electrical

As title, would like to know please?
Thanks.
Peter.

Comment: Using an oversized fuse is dangerous - the other components are designed to handle 13A and you're counting on the fuse to blow at 13A, if the fuse doesn't blow until 16A, the components will be overloaded.

Comment: https://www.pat-testing-training.net/articles/20a-mains-plug-fuse.php implies, (and I concur from check a reputable supplier with a huge range) that such a fuse would be from a dodgy source as well.  What's your need? In practice a 13A fuse will take more than 13A for quite a while (we found we'd been drawing 32A through two 13A fuses when the 30A breaker tripped before the fuses).  The plugs and cables may not be able to take it regardless of the fuse.  If it's for a 16A caravan type circuit, you're unlikely to be drawing more than 13A anyway

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not it can be done, I cannot recommend it. By putting a 16A fuse in a UK domestic plug you are potentially overloading the cable (max for a UK domestic plug is 15A rated according to [this pat testing website](https://www.pat-testing-training.net/articles/20a-mains-plug-fuse.php)).

A spur off a ring main, using 2.0mm<sup>2</sup> twin and earth cable is rated for 20A. Two 16A plugs into the sockets on that spur could hence significantly overload it, starting a fire in your walls.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's illegal.

Any device that isn't intended to be fitted with a plug, cannot be fitted with a plug.

Any fuses must comply with BS 1362, which allows for a max of 13A.

Your device (Immersion heater?) must be connected to a suitable circuit by a fused connection unit (FCU) - just adding a 16A load to an existing circuit would be a terrible idea.